# Simple-html-dom list ordering nested without class

Tags: php, arrays, simple-html-dom

i am literally stuck with getting these ul/li elements in one row.
Only first li has class, others are in another ul but without class or id. i tried multiple searches and loops, but can't get it right.
Below results returns too many rows where elements don't fit together.

Can someone help me?

idealy the result from below example would be:

'part', 'desc', 'qty'
'106128-001','LBL, BLNK,THERMAL PRINT','1'
'106128-004','LBL, BLNK THERMAL,RECT 2.40x4','1'

HTML example

```
<div id='tab1' class="section tab" data-position="auto" style="max-height:none;">
<ul class="links">
            <li id="innertab1"><a href="#combom0" class="collapsed">106128-001</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="combom0" class="tab1 cols2 compare">
            <li style="border: none;">
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        
                        <li><strong>Description: </strong>LBL, BLNK,THERMAL PRINT</li>
                        <li><strong>Qty: </strong>1</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
<ul class="links">
            <li id="innertab1"><a href="#combom1" class="collapsed">106128-004</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="combom1" class="tab1 cols2 compare">
            <li style="border: none;">
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        
                        <li><strong>Description: </strong>LBL, BLNK THERMAL,RECT 2.40x4</li>
                        <li><strong>Qty: </strong>1</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

My poor attempt with trying to count rows:

```
$search = $html->find('div[id=tab1]',0);
$i=0;
$alles=array();

    foreach ($search->find('* li') as $test){
    if(!empty($test->innertext)){
        if($i>3){$i=0;}
        $i++;
        if($i==1){
                echo $alles_li['part'] = strip_tags($test->innertext);
        }
        if($i==2){
                // don't need this, bad stripping
                strip_tags($test->innertext);
        }
        if($i==3){
                $alles_li['desc'] = strip_tags($test->innertext);
        }
        if($i==4){
            $alles_li['qty'] = strip_tags($test->innertext);
        }

    }
// if less than 3 elements don't add

    if(count($alles_li)==3){    
        
        $alles[]=$alles_li;

    }
}
```

Comment: The outer `<ul>` elements all have a class called `compare`. Fetch them, then you can fetch their child `<ul>` elements (as each only has one) and extract `<li>` elements from those.

Comment: @El_Vanja there are two main ul which are connected, `<ul class="links">` which has one,  and `<ul id="combom0" class="tab1 cols2 compare">` which is not child, but has two `<li>` elements. Maybe i don't understand what you mean?

Comment: yeah match the collapsed, grab the href then match the li's https://3v4l.org/lO4Eb

Comment: My bad, I missed that one. Though you can connect them as they are siblings. Do you have to use Simple HTML Dom?

Comment: thank you @LawrenceCherone, that is native DOM, right? now i have to study that :) Can i limit it to specific DIV?

Comment: @El_Vanja unfortunatelly i am not an experienced programmer, i check it and it seemed fairly simple to use. well until i hit the wall with this issue

Comment: The reason I asked was because Lawrence's solution was rather good and it uses a native functionality. Just wanted to make sure you can use it instead of SHD.

Comment: His solution is perfect! i tried it now, but i had to load html with simplehtmldom for specific div `<div id='tab1'` and perfect array was there. Now i will have to learn how to use native  to manipulate files.  How do i mark his answer as correct?

Comment: You can't because he didn't post it as an answer, only as a comment. If he posts an answer, you'll see a check mark for accepting it.